# Mix SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory and HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory

Tags: spring, proxy, basic-authentication, resttemplate

I need to set a proxy with `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` and I need to set basic autenticathion for a web service with `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`.

I am using Spring `restTemplate` services and I need to mix botch `factorys`.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create HttpClient to call rest services, you can use

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
```

Details about basic auth are explained at http://www.baeldung.com/2012/04/16/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring-3-1/

Comment: I have to set a user and a password for the service but not for the Proxy.